# Python doesn't recognize -1 as False?

Tags: python

I recently wrote a Python program that used:

```
if s.find('something'):
```

or

```
if s.find('something')==True:
```

but nothing worked correctly until I used:

```
if s.find('something') >0
```

That's the only way I could get an accurate True decision in my program.

It seems -1 result wasn't recognized as False. Successful finds weren't recognized as True either. So looking for -1 (False) or a positive number >0 (True) was the only thing that worked for me.

What was I doing wrong? This can't be the way Python works, can it?

Comment: `find` returns the index that the substring was found at. Since 0 is a valid index, it can't be used as a 'not found' code, so it returns -1 instead. The only falsey number in Python is 0. If you just want to check for containment, use `"something" in s` instead, which returns a boolean.

Answer (score 12):

You are interpreting the return value of [`find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) incorrectly. The documentation states:

> **`str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`**
>
> Return the lowest index in the string where substring `sub` is found, such that `sub` is contained in the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` if `sub` is not found.

Of all numbers, Python considers only [0 to be false; -1 is true](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). As `find` returns the index of the beginning of the match, and 0 is a valid index to a string, -1 is returned when no match was found.

Thus your code should rather* be:

```
if s.find('something') != -1:
```

or

```
if s.find('something') >= 0:
```

Though they're not the most Pythonic either, if you just want to see if `s` contains `'something'` - see below.

---

Now, about your second example: the `bool` constant `False` compares equal to `0`:

```
>>> 0 == False
True
```

and `bool` constant `True` only equal to number `1`:

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 2 == True
False
```

Thus the expression `s.find('something') == True` would be totally equivalent with `s.find('something') == 1`; and the whole expression would evaluate to `True` only if the `s` would be of form `xsomethingxxxx`, with a match for `something` starting at the 2nd character (index 1).

---

The documentation for `str.find` continues with the following note:

> **Note**
>
> The `find()` method **should be used only if you need to know the position of `sub`.** To check if `sub` is a substring or not, use the `in` operator:
>
> ```
> >>> 'Py' in 'Python'
> True
> ```

Thus the form that is the most Pythonic for the problem in your question is

```
if 'something' in s:
```

---

As suggested by @myaut, if you *need* the position of `'something'` within `s` and expect it to contain the value, you should use [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) instead, which will throw an exception if the `substring` was not found within the string.

```
 try:
     position = s.index('something')
     print("'something' found at", position)
 except ValueError:
     print(s, "does not contain the substring 'something'")
```

Comment: So the problem is not how python performs boolean evaluation of numeric values, but the way the OP was interpreting the return value from `str.find` , right?

Comment: @heltonbiker, right.  BTW Antti, I'm pretty sure that you mean "should NOT be used", please edit accordingly...

Comment: Do not compare booleans with `==` or at least do `bool(1) == True` (see PEP-8). You miss `__bool__` operator that actually decides which values are `True` and which are `False`.

Comment: @myaut I am very well aware of that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Even if you aware, it may confuse OP like that confused me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Python thinks `0` is `False`, not `-1`.

As you can see in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html), Python tries hard to have many different kinds of `False` values:

- `False`
- `None`
- `0` of any numeric type: `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
- any empty sequence: `''`, `()`, `[]`.
- any empty mapping: `{}`.

Your intuitive notion that `-1` should be `False` in Python makes some sense, but that is just not how Python was designed. Zeros and empties are falsey in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check wether a string is contained in another, use:

```
if 'something' in s:
    print 'something in %s' % s
else:
    print 'bad luck'
```

Answer (score 0):

`-1` as an error code came from C, but that leads to spaghetti code of checking return values.

Python has more reliable way to report an error: [raise an Exception](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html). I.e. `str.index` does that:

```
>>> 'abcde'.find('cd')
2
>>> 'abcde'.index('cd')
2
>>> 'abcde'.find('zx')
-1
>>> 'abcde'.index('zx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: substring not found
```

And of course to check if string contains substring you should use `in` operator:

```
>>> 'ab' in 'abcde'
True
>>> 'zx' in 'abcde'
False
```

Speaking of `if` statements you should note that comparing to boolean is a bad idea (check for example [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Every type in Python defines its own rules which values are considered "True": [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to verify what is the bool value of it;

```
bool(-1)
True

bool(0)
False

bool('')
False
```

and so on,

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing something wrong.

In python `bool` inherit from `int`. `False` is `0` and `True` is `1`. You can try `int(True)` and `int(False)`. If you try `bool(0)` you will get `False`, but if you write `bool(-1)` or `bool(1)` you always will get `True`. If you use `find` you will get `-1` so you need to use `>= 0`. You can find `'something'` inside `'something else'`.

You can write `if 'something' in s:`. I think that find is deprecated.